# XML Schema inheritance

Tags: xml, schema, restriction

Here is a simplified XML Schema example I have written:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://pius.lt" xmlns="http://pius.lt" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="person">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="sex" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="user">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="person">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="admin">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="user">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string" fixed="admin@pius.lt"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Error I get is:

```
Not valid.
Error - Line 22, 31: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 31; rcase-Recurse.2: There is not a complete functional mapping between the particles.
Error - Line 22, 31: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 31; derivation-ok-restriction.5.4.2: Error for type 'admin'.  The particle of the type is not a valid restriction of the particle of the base.
```

What am I missing?

P.S. Is it possible to apply pattern restriction on that "email" field? Something like `.+@example.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you derive by restriction you need to provide the *complete* content model in the subtype - anything you don't say is allowed in the subtype is assumed to be forbidden.

So the way your schema is written the `admin` type would *only* be allowed to contain an `email` element and nothing else, but this is not a valid restriction of `user` because an element of type `user` *must* have exactly one `name`, then one `email`, then one `sex`, then one `password` element as children.

You're falling foul of rule 2.2 under http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#rcase-Recurse:

> All particles in the {particles} of B which are not mapped to by any particle in the {particles} of R are ·emptiable· as defined by Particle Emptiable (§3.9.6).

i.e. anything you want to leave out in the restricted type must have been optional in the parent to start with - any instance of the restricted type must also be a valid instance of the parent type from which it is restricted.

If you genuinely do want the `admin` type to contain *only* the `email` element then you'd have to mark the other elements of `person` and `user` with `minOccurs="0"`, but I suspect that really you want

```
<xs:complexType name="admin">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="user">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string" fixed="admin@pius.lt"/>
                <xs:element name="sex" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```